# calling e.stopImmediatePropagation() from onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, onclick

How do I get the event object from an `onclick` attribute?

I have tried:

```
<a href="something.html" onclick="function(e){e.stopImmediatePropagation();}">Click me</a>
```

Also, I have tried this:

```
<a href="something.html" onclick="console.log(this);">Click me</a>
```

But the console just shows the `<a>` element.

Comment: Use the jQuery `.click()` instead of the `onclick` attribute

Comment: Just curious, if you're using jQuery, why are you also using an inline `onclick` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd have to define the function in a `<script/>` tag elsewhere.

Would it be that bad to simply use something like:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#something_link').click(function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
</script>
<a href="something.html" id="something_link">Click me</a>
```

Comment: The second part is correct, not the first part. `stopImmediatePropogation()` is part of the jQuery API. It only works on the event object passed by its own event handler wrappers.

Comment: @lucas_jones I would like to do something like that, but I am using Ruby on Rails v 2.3.10.  This is really to add some AJAX goodness to a delete link.  A delete link uses the onclick attribute to dynamically create/submit a form and return false.  It works fine for normal page request, but trying to AJAX-ify it is troublesome b/c the event continues to propagate.

Comment: @lucas_jones And I am trying not to deviate too far from source code when I modify the link_to helper.  I think I will look at Rails v 3.x source code to see if they implement this functionality via unobtrusive javascript or inline javascript.

Comment: @nick_craver I am doing inline javascript (instead of unobtrusive javascript) b/c I am trying to minimize modification to a Ruby on Rails v 2.3.10 delete link, which uses the link_to helper to generate inline javascript.

Comment: @Teddy: Maybe try `onclick="return false;"`? I know it has a slightly different effect, but it might still work.

Comment: @lucas_jones onclick="return false;" is already there.  It works for a normal page request, but doesn't stop event from propagating if I try to do AJAX.