# Use jQuery to find an event object

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick, jquery-events

jQuery has wonderful selectors for DOM elements, but can you 'select' an event object.

That is, if I use inline JavaScript on the `onclick` attribute of an element, could I have a selector to find that event object so I can act on it.

I know I could do something like this:

```
$("a#some_link").click(function(event){//act on event here});
```

But how would I find the event object if inline JavaScript was used:

```
<a href="somepage.html" onclick="alert('how do I get my event oject?');">click me</a>
```

This question is a supplement to an earlier question: [calling e.stopImmediatePropagation() from onclick attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318976/calling-e-stopimmediatepropagation-from-onclick-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onclick = "alert(event.type);return false;"

<a id="some_link" href="somepage.html" onclick="alert(event.type);return false;">click me</a>
```

[**Test it**](http://jsbin.com/azocu4)

Answer (score 1):

Simple `$('a').attr('onclick')` gets you that data. In Firefox it's wrapped with `function() {  }`

Answer (score 0):

Well this should find 'onclick' events, I do not believe it picks up the jQuery bound events.

```
$("a,input").filter(function() {
    return $.isFunction(this.onclick)
});
```

If there are any other tag types you might have such an event on, then you would need to add them, you can use `"*"` as the selector, but that is quite slow.